Validate the size of incoming request
I have a following controllerClass, which takes a request and process it. It works fine with below code.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user/id")
public class UserController {

  private final UserName userName;

  @Autowired
  public UserController(final UserName userName) {
    this.userName = Objects.requireNonNull(userName, "Not found");
  }

  @JsonRequestMapping(method = POST)
  public ResponseEntity<UserResponse> validate(
      @RequestBody UserRequest UserRequest,
      @RequestHeader(required = false) String validation) {

…
  }

However, I want to add a validation to check request size, to avoid extra-large malicious requests being made, and reject the request if size exceeds a particular value.
I tried:
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
…
@RequestBody(@Size(max = 200)) UserRequest UserRequest

But this is giving me Cannot find method 'value', which I am not sure why. Is this the right way to achieve the validation that i want, if yes what am i missing with above?

the issue with validating your object @Size if want to use validation you need to annotate with @Valid
@RequestBody(@Valid @RequestBody UserRequest UserRequest)

//in object

@Size(max=200)
private String fieldname;

or you can go with
@Valid @Size(max = 200) @RequestBody UserRequest userRequest)


I tried @Valid @Size(max = 200) @RequestBody UserRequest userRequest), and then curl -v --location 'localhost:1234/user/id' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header "Authorization: ***" --data-binary '@file_500MB.json' and the request just passes through though the request body is of 500MB

this might be an issue with spring I think there might some other annotation instead of size to check them in mb
instead you can create a custom annotation for validation
